# ServiceStack.Aws support "last evaluated key" on DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

In DynamoDB, when limit property has been set up, DynamoDB will return a "last evaluated key" that is used for pagination (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination))

I want to know if ServiceStack.Aws support this feature (for .NET c# version), or if I need to use directly the AWSSDK client.

### Edit

I want to implement a server side pagination. How can achieve this ussing PocoDynamo? My code looks like this

```
public IList<Company> GetCompanies(string shortName, ref string lastKeyEvaluated)
{
   IList<Company> data = null;
   using (AmazonDynamoDBClient awsDynamoDbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient())
   {
      IPocoDynamo dbDynamo = new PocoDynamo(awsDynamoDbClient);
      var queryExpression = dbDynamo.FromQuery<Company>(c => c.ShortName == shortName);
      data = dbDynamo.Query(queryExpression, 10); //How can i pass lastEvaluatedKey?
      var awsdkClient = dbDynamo.DynamoDb; //Can i get last evaluated key from original AWSDK client?
   }
   return data;
}
```

### Edit 2

In some answers, they told to me that I need to use a delegate parameter. But, it seems that this delegate expect a QueryResponse object, and return a `IEnumerable<T>`. From QueryResponse, I know that can I get `LastEvaluatedKey`, but how this delegate can return the last evaluated key? It's possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

In [PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) when you use the [Query or Scan API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#query-and-scan-expressions) that return an `IEnumerable<T>`, i.e:

```
public interface IPocoDynamo
{
    //...
    IEnumerable<T> ScanAll<T>();
    IEnumerable<T> Scan<T>(ScanRequest request, Func<ScanResponse, IEnumerable<T>> fn);
    IEnumerable<T> Scan<T>(ScanExpression<T> request);
    IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(QueryExpression<T> request);
    IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(QueryRequest request);
    IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(QueryRequest request, Func<QueryResponse, IEnumerable<T>> fn);
}
```

PocoDynamo returns a lazy sequence that transparently sends multiple paged requests to fetch as many results as needed using the `LastEvaluatedKey` Response to fetch the next page of results.

For API's that accept a **limit** and return a concrete `List<T>` the results still use `LastEvaluatedKey` to fetch the results but they're instead eagerly fetched into a concrete `List<T>` before being returned.

Comment: I want to implement a server side pagination. I can't find a method in PocoDynamo, that accepts a last evaluated key. In the other hand, can't find a method that can retrieve last evaluated key. Would be great a overloading method that accepts last evaluated key, and a way to retrieve this value too.

Comment: @VladimirVenegas PocoDynamo API's are managed queries that takes care of the pagination behind-the-scenes. But the Scan and Query Expressions inherits from ScanRequest/QueryRequest which contains `ExclusiveStartKey` which is where to set the LastEvaluatedKey. If you want to take over and do your own pagination you can access the AWS underlying `db.DynamoDb` client and [do your own pagination](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/1083a58932869be13b2679ef9bef36e7ed1b1bfb/tests/ServiceStack.Aws.DynamoDbTests/UseCases/DynamoDbTodoExample.cs#L202).

Comment: @VladimirVenegas The Scan/Query API's that accept a `Func<,>` callback allow you to access the response which contains the `LastEvaluatedKey`. Adding any additional API's that accept a LastEvaluatedKey would be confusing, you wouldn't know what the behavior of the API would be.

Comment: Thanks mythz. Could you provide me an example on how achieve this, using delegate parameter?

Because the signature of delegate parameter, need to be QueryResponse as input parameter, and IEnumerable<T> as output parameter. How this delegate can return the last evaluated key?

Comment: @VladimirVenegas the `Func<QueryResponse, IEnumerable<T>>` callback injects the `QueryResponse` which contains the `LastEvaluatedKey`, but this is an advanced managed API - I'd ignore it and access the AWS `db.DynamoDb` client directly.